# Timestamp Format Issue (NiFi's PutDatabaseRecord)

Tags: apache-nifi

Getting following error when inserting a datetime into a MSSQL database using the **PutDatabaseRecord (1.9.2) processor in Nifi**.

Datatype in table is **DateTime**

[image: Error Message]

Reading a simple csv-file:

```
TALKGROUP_REF;FLEET_REF;TALKGROUP_ID;TALKGROUP_NAME;GROUP_TYPE;DISPATCHER_REF;MULTIGROUP_REF;OWNER;FNE_STATE;ADDL_ATTRVAR;LAST_USER_MODIFIED;TIME_STAMP;FNE_OID
3345;424;123456790847070;LOK-KJX-A;T;;;1 53133303;O;;NBA;2014-02-27 15:11:13;
3346;424;123456790847071;LOK-KJX-1;T;;;1 53133303;O;;NBA;2017-05-10 21:29:26;
3347;424;123456790847072;LOK-KJX-2;T;;;1 53133303;O;;NBA;2017-05-10 21:29:35;
3348;424;123456790847073;LOK-KJX-3;T;;;1 53133303;O;;NBA;2017-05-10 21:29:35;
3350;424;123456790847075;LOK-KJX-5;T;;;1 53133303;O;;NBA;2017-05-10 21:29:35;
```

[image: Workflow]

Schema used:

```
{ "type" : "record", "name" : "mibas_t005_talkgroup", "fields" : [  
{ "name" : "talkgroup_ref", "type" : ["null","long"] },
{ "name" : "fleet_ref", "type" : ["null","long"] },
{ "name" : "talkgroup_id", "type" : ["null","long"] },
{ "name" : "talkgroup_name", "type" : ["null","string"] },
{ "name" : "group_type", "type" : ["null","string"] },
{ "name" : "dispatcher_ref", "type" : ["null","string"] },
{ "name" : "multigroup_ref", "type" : ["null","string"] },
{ "name" : "owner_", "type" : ["null","string"] },
{ "name" : "fne_state", "type" : ["null","string"] },
{ "name" : "addl_attrvar", "type" : ["null","string"] },
{ "name" : "last_user_modified", "type" : ["null","string"] },
{ "name" : "time_stamp", "type" : ["null", { "type":"long", "logicaltype":"timestamp-millis"} ]},
{ "name" : "fne_oid", "type" : ["null","string"] }]}
```

Timestamp Format: '**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**'

[image: Processors config]
[image: Controller Service Details]

Comment: You'll need to show us the code you're using. If the column a `datetime` or `datetime2` (or a `datetimeoffset`)? `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` is ambiguous format with SQL Server (depending on the data type and language), so you would be better an unambiguous one such as `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Also to be clear, what datatype is your column? You mention timestamp which is a datatype in sql server that has nothing to do with dates or times.

Comment: The data format in the table is Datetime. The format given  "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" is as according to the description given for the processor and works for other workflows. Was not able to submit the code because of its length, hence the processor photos.

Comment: @Larnu yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss is not a valid pattern for the processor.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was changing the datatype definition in the schema from ***logicaltype*** to ***logicalType*** (Upper case T there for you). wtf!!!

Eg:
*{ "name" : "time_stamp", "type" : ["null", { "type":"long", "***logicalType***":"timestamp-millis"}*

The irritating part is that it validates. No warning! But, if you mistakenly use *String* instead of the correct *string* (lower case S) or *Type* instead of *type* in you schema, your schema will not validate and you can correct it.